# After Effects - Convert Repeater object into individual shapes

Tags: repeater, explode, trim, break, after-effects

I just want to explode / break the individual shapes created by repeater and trim options. Is there any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this script to bake the repeater.

http://aescripts.com/shape-repeater-baker/

Comment: Thanks for the link but just wondering if there is inbuilt option for this.

Comment: As far as I know. No. There is no built in option for that. Thats why Nik wrote that script.

Comment: Thanks for confirming, I will try the script.